# How to convert List<Integer> to ArrayOfInt (not to be mistaken with int[])

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm using a SOAP service written in `WCF` for my Java application and one of my service has a parameter of type `int[]`. When adding the service in Java, this `int[]` is converted to a type known as `ArrayOfInt` for serialization purposes. When I declare such type, it does not have any method to append to it. So, I tried to cast my `List<Integer>` to that type using:

```
List<Integer> Items = new ArrayList();
//Appending some integers to the list and checking if it has values 
// Then
com.microsoft.schemas._2003._10.serialization.arrays.ArrayOfint Ai = (com.microsoft.schemas._2003._10.serialization.arrays.ArrayOfint) Items;
org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.inventorymanwcf.ArrayOfReceiptModel R = man.getBasicHttpBindingIManagement().sell(Ai, Login.Username);
```

Then the code caused an error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.microsoft.schemas._2003._10.serialization.arrays.ArrayOfint
```

My question is how handle that type, how to convert my list to an `ArrayOfInt` ?

Comment: Did you try converting the list to int[] and then initializing ArrayOfint with that?

Comment: @DhanushGopinath: Yes in the first place, int[] is not compatible with ArrayOfInt, no implicit casting

Comment: Can you share the ArrayOfInt Code or API doc?

Comment: @DhanushGopinath: It's not mine, it's part of the JAX-WS

Comment: There should be a documentation, right? How do you know what to set on that class without documentation. Sorry if I am sounding naive, am not used to working with MS API's

Comment: @DhanushGopinath: As I mentioned in the question, no method to set just a get method in there, so the doc was no help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to something like [this](https://code.google.com/p/yet-another-tridion-blog/source/browse/trunk/Core+Service+Java+Client/src/com/microsoft/schemas/_2003/_10/serialization/arrays/ArrayOfint.java?spec=svn5&r=5) it is obvious, that you cant create the array by itself. You could however override it: `new ArrayOfint(){ @Override public List<Integer> getInt() { return Arrays.asList(insertIntarrayHere);
}}` or `new ArrayOfint(){ @Override public List<Integer> getInt() { return insertListHere;
}}`